# Selecting latest row from each site?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, business-intelligence

I am trying to select the latest row from each customer site from the following script:

```
select   "CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE"."VALUE" as "SO_NUMBER",
     "CONTRACT"."END_DATE" as "CONTRACT_END_DATE",
     "ALERT"."LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP" as "LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP_1",
     "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."VALUE" as "DP_UPLD_DATA_VALUE",
     "SITE"."NAME" as "SITE_NAME",
     "SITE"."LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP" as "LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP",
     "CONTRACT_TYPE"."NAME" as "CONTRACT_TYPE_NAME",
     "ALERT"."USER_ID" as "ALERT_USER_ID",
     "ALERT"."ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_TIME" as "NOTES_TIMESTAMP",
     "ALERT"."EVENT" as "ALERT_EVENT",
     "ALERT"."ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_NOTE" as "NOTES",
     "ALERT"."CASE_NO" as "ALERT_CASE_NO",
     "SITE"."ID" as "SITE_ID" 
 from   "DB"."ALERT" "ALERT",
    "DB"."DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA" "DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA",
    "DB"."COMPONENT" "COMPONENT",
    "DB"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT" "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT",
    "DB"."CONTRACT" "CONTRACT",
    "DB"."CONTRACT_TYPE" "CONTRACT_TYPE",
    "DB"."CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE" "CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE",
    "DB"."SITE" "SITE" 
 where   "SITE"."ID"="CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE"."SITE_ID"
 and     "CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE"."SITE_ID"="CONTRACT"."SITE_ID"
 and     "CONTRACT"."CONTRACT_TYPE_ID"="CONTRACT_TYPE"."ID"
 and     "CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE"."SITE_ID"="COMPONENT"."SITE_ID"
 and     "COMPONENT"."ID"="COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."COMPONENT_ID"
 and     "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."ID"="DATA_POINT_UPLOAD_DATA"."COMPONENT_DATA_POINT_ID"
 and     "ALERT"."SITE_ID"="CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE"."SITE_ID"
  and    "CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE"."NAME" ='SO#' 
   and   "COMPONENT_DATA_POINT"."NAME" ='State'
   and   "SITE"."EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID" ='250';
```

Current output:

... 5,000 output ...

```
SO_NUMBER                      CONTRACT_END_DATE LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP_1            DP_UPLD_DATA_VALUE                                                                                   SITE_NAME                                                                                            LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP              CONTRACT_TYPE_NAME                                                           ALERT_USER_ID NOTES_TIMESTAMP                     ALERT_EVENT                                        NOTES                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ALERT_CASE_NO                                         SITE_ID
------------------------------ ----------------- ----------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------- ----------
144732                         30-JUN-19         14-JUN-17 04.57.07.119266000 AM     Some_Event_Occurred                                                                                  Customer Name                                                                                  10-NOV-16 08.19.47.000000000 PM     Some Contract                                                                   1169 09-JUN-17 03.34.10.019229000 PM     Some Notes Entered                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ABC123
Only 5,000 rows currently supported in a script results
 5,000 rows selected
```

Expected Output:

```
SO_NUMBER                      CONTRACT_END_DATE LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP_1            DP_UPLD_DATA_VALUE                                                                                   SITE_NAME                                                                                            LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP              CONTRACT_TYPE_NAME                                                           ALERT_USER_ID NOTES_TIMESTAMP                     ALERT_EVENT                                        NOTES                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ALERT_CASE_NO                                         SITE_ID
------------------------------ ----------------- ----------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------- ----------
145732                         30-JUN-19         14-JUN-17 04.57.07.119266000 AM     Some_Run_Event                                                                                      Customer 1                                                                                  10-NOV-16 08.19.47.000000000 PM      Contract                                                                   1169 09-JUN-17 03.34.10.019229000 PM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        100763
146733                         30-JUN-19         10-JUN-17 03.20.06.396989000 AM     Some_Run_Event                                                                                      Customer 2                                                                                   10-NOV-16 08.19.47.000000000 PM      Contract                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              100764
144734                         30-JUN-19         10-JUN-17 03.29.07.172041000 AM     Some_Run_Event                                                                                      Customer 3                                                                                   10-NOV-16 08.19.47.000000000 PM      Contract                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              100765
144835                         30-JUN-19         10-JUN-17 03.44.06.692450000 AM     Some_Run_Event                                                                                      Customer 4                                                                                   10-NOV-16 08.19.47.000000000 PM      Contract                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              100766
144936                         30-JUN-19         10-JUN-17 06.30.06.828320000 AM     Some_Run_Event                                                                                      Customer 5                                                                                  10-NOV-16 08.19.47.000000000 PM      Contract                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               100767
144937                         30-JUN-19         10-JUN-17 06.58.06.163756000 AM     Some_Run_Event                                                                                      Customer 6                                                                                   10-NOV-16 08.19.47.000000000 PM      Contract                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              100768
```

I am trying to get the latest row from each Site ID, instead of thousands of rows from each Site ID.

Comment: What exactly is the "last row"?  In order by what?  Your query has no ORDER BY so the rows can come back in any order.

Comment: The latest row, not last row.  I am trying to populate the latest one row for each site instead of populating every row for each site.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "latest" you mean the latest date in alert.last_updated_timestamp, then create a subquery that uses an aggregate to get the max() value of this date for each SiteID, then join that subquery to the query you already have to limit the output to just those times.

Or if "latest" means something else, then adjust accordingly; the same technique will apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use

"SITE"."ID" as "SITE_ID",

ROW_NUMBER()  over (partition by SITE.ID order by ALERT.LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP desc) as temp_col

as last column in this existing select statement and add a outer query to filter SELECT * FROM (.... your existing query)  where temp_col = 1